# How can I know what a change has occurred in a list of objects knowing its original state

Tags: java, arrays, math, logarithm

We have an array of objects that have their 'IDs'.

Array

```
Object { id = "test"}
Object { id = "test1"}
Object { id = "test2"}
```

Is it possible to understand what a change has occurred in this list once I know its original state?

Operations:

- added one or more new object only?
- deleted one or more object only?
- renamed one or more objects only?
- added and renamed and deleted objects?

How can I distinguish these cases and is it possible without having any other information about them?

Rules:

- If all objects are deleted and after that added with the same IDs > in this case the operations that are used are not important once the final result is the same, for me these arrays are the same.
- Each object has a unique ID

Note: if it matters, I use Java.

Comment: The hard problem is to find the minimum number of changes, because "everything was deleted and then everything new was added" is probably not helpful.

Comment: If I add and remove the same object (at least one having the same id) multiple times but the final state is the same as the original one, would it really matter what has happened in between? What exactly do you need that information for? What kind of "migration" do you refer to?

Comment: In this case, it does not matter if they are the same at the end. Only those operations I have explained are possible and each ID is unique.

Comment: You may use getter and setter to change the list, and then check the changes

Comment: This is not possible in this case. The object description is stored in a file.

Comment: @MBaev maybe you find this interesting https://github.com/Ruslan08/trigger-collections
this project if actively developing